# Require help locating and identifying Star Wars universe ship

Tags: star-wars

I require assistance identifying a piece of Star Wars hardware; a ship. Timeline-wise, it first  appeared on an early Tim Zahn novel, used to escort ships to one of Lando's newest enterprises (a Mercury-like world, with a city/mining station that was carried on the dark side by AT-ATs).

This ship… well… it looked, from the description, like the Warsie version of *Sunshine*'s Icarus II.

Like I said, I need help please. What is that ship, capabilities, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are called "[Shieldships](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shieldship)"; and indeed they appeared in the very first SW book by Zahn, *Heir to the Empire (Thrawn Trilogy #1)*.

Capabilities listed on Wookieepedia in detail, but included:

- Cargo capacity 20 metric tons
- Defensive turbolaser turret (source: [The Official Star Wars Fact File](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File))

*(Image from Wookieepedia article)*

[image: Millennium Falcon approaching a Shieldship]